# AWS SQS policy not automatically modified when creating a subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Depending on which page I create a subscription for a SNS topic to a SQS queue (both belonging to the same account) from within the AWS console, I notice a difference in how SQS policy for the queue is updated.

- When I initially created the subscription from the SNS topic page in
  the console, the queue's access policy did not get updated.
- When I created the policy from SQS queue's page, I see the queue policy is
  updated automatically allowing "SQS:SendMessage" from the SNS topic
  ARN.

Is the difference in behavior between these two use cases intentional? Is there a reason behind why creating the subscription from SNS topic page does not update the permission automatically?

Comment: AWS console just does different things under the hood sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any specially reason for that. Its just **inconsistencies in how AWS Console works**. In fact, there is plenty of such inconsistencies in AWS Console.

The most basic example of that is when you delete a resource. Some resources will just delete without asking anything, others will force you to  write "delete", others "delete me", or "permanently delete", or write "resource-name" or confirm something else.